# opensource CRM/ERP system in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, open-source, crm, erp

Do you know some opensource CRM/ERP system like [xlsuite.org](http://xlsuite.org)? XLSUITE is very old for me and my server. 
I need opensource system, because I can customize it for my job and I know RoR.

Comment: This is not a programming question, please [read the faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I need opensource system, because I can use it and customize it for my firm and other partners. Is it ok? Where can I write questions like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example I know off the top of my head is: http://www.fatfreecrm.com/